# Como reproduzir um vídeo automaticamente no google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vídeo, html5-video, reprodutor-de-video

Desenvolvi um site para uma empresa e esta pediu um video logo abaixo do menu, e que este vídeo fosse reproduzido automaticamente, até ai nada de mais utilizei o seguinte código:

```
<video  preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop style="height: 700px;" >
        <!--<source src="assets/video/entrada.mp4" type="video/mp4">-->
        <source src="assets/video/enter.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Seu navegador não suporta HTML5.
    </video>
```

Só que aconeteceu uma coisa neste código nos navegadores Firefox, Edge, e Opera funcionaram bem a reprodução automatica, porém no google Chrome, que é o mais utilizado, não!
Portanto a minha suplica de ajuda como faço para reproduzir este vido automaticamente no Chrome ja tentei também via iframe como no codigo abaixo:

```
<iframe width="1520" height="700" src="video.html" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

Comment: Tente colocar apena `autoplay` **não** use dessa forma  `autoplay="true"`. Faz um teste ai pra ver. Não tenho certeza se vai funcionar, mas vale o teste né...

Comment: Não funcionou hugocsl, mas mesmo assim obrigado pela tentativa. Acho uma sacanagem da google isto, vou continuar procurando se caso achar algo que possa me ajudar posta aí vlw.

Comment: Tenta por `muted` na tag do video, as vezes sem o som habilitado ele permite o autoplay...

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com esse artigo no [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay), a partir da versão 53 do Chrome a reprodução automática é respeitada pelo navegador, se o vídeo estiver sem som.

**Para isso use:** `autoplay muted`

```
<video autoplay muted>
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

> Além disso, a reprodução desativada agora pode ser iniciada usando o
>   método `play()`. Anteriormente, `play()` só iniciaria a reprodução se
>   viesse de um gesto do usuário, como um clique no botão. Fonte: [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay)

**Reprodução aumática com JS:**

```js
document.getElementById('video1').play();
```

```html
<video src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/247833422.hd.mp4?s=8d872a36d3dbe7f74e9613ab144d088b5bab6649&profile_id=174" id="video1" poster="" preload autoplay loop></video>
```